# Maven: Run main class from the pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I've created a Java based tool that runs on some data and generates output files in a target directory.

I'm using Maven to build this tool.

I have the following requirement:
  While building the tool, in the pom.xml, after the jar is created --> Run the main class of this tool to generate the output files and when it finishes zip the target directory.

I've managed to zip everything when the build ends using

```
maven-assembly-plugin
```

but I don't know how to primarily run the main class before the zipping...

Any idea?

Comment: You can use exec-maven-plugin which can be bound to the life cycle and use it like this way? But without detailed information what you exactly try to accomplish it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) to make an executable jar, including the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I ended up using 2 Maven plugins:

1. maven-antrun-plugin  : for running the jar and generating the output directory.
2. maven-assembly-plugin : for zipping the directory.

I'm sure there are other ways, but this worked well for me.
Hope it helps someone...